# RaspberryPi 4 with Java 13.0.1

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, installation, raspbian

Does anybody know how I can install `Java` 13.0.1 on a `RaspberryPi` 4?

Because I use `[Java 13.0.1]`[1](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html) on my WindowsEngine and so I wrote and exported my JavaApplication with Java 13.0.1 but the `RaspberryPi` only supports a licensed Version of [`Java 11.0.5`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html) which is not available for free.

[image: bia]

Comment: You should try OpenJDK. Little to no licensing encumbrances with the free/open source software...

Comment: [link] https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/637567997845700608/645225734893207562/unknown.png 
Yeah, I already tried this with: **sudo apt-get install openjdk-13-jdk** 
But it doesn't work with jdk 13.. see image-link .. With jdk 8 / 11 it works but I don't wan't jdk 8 or 11

Answer (score 4):

Surprised nobody has posted about this yet; you can totally install recent versions of Java on Raspbian.

In this example, I'll be using an [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net) OpenJDK build to install Java 14 on Raspbian Stretch.

```sh
# 1) Download the armhf jdk14 binary
wget 'https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/pool/main/a/adoptopenjdk-14-hotspot/adoptopenjdk-14-hotspot_14.0.0+36-2_armhf.deb'

# 2) now install it, and don't worry if it spits out a ton of errors, this is normal
sudo dpkg -i 'adoptopenjdk-14-hotspot_14.0.0+36-2_armhf.deb'

# 3) install missing dependencies
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And that's it!  Running `java -version` now yields:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "14" 2020-03-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14+36)
OpenJDK Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 14+36, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: This method didn't work for me with an older ARMv7 Pi. What ended up working was using LibericaJDK - documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62912054/13762264_)

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
I decided to download [Java 11.0.5](https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/entwicklung/java-se-development-kit/) to my windows engine and build the JavaProjects as a Java 11.0.5 Application.

Answer (score 1):

Paying for any version of Java is getting ripped off: don't do it ever, unless you need to comply with licensing for a professional project (or something).

There isn't currently something you can install from `apt-get`, but Bell-SW has Java 13 packages for ARMv7 (you just have to scroll down) and they have instructions for how to install.

https://bell-sw.com/pages/java-13.0.2/

For free.

Answer (score 0):

or just use the AdoptOpenJDK repos:

```
echo "deb https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptopenjdk.list
wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search adoptopenjdk
sudo apt-get install adoptopenjdk-15-hotspot
```

Those are the condensed instructions for [Linux RPM and DEB installer packages](https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html)

`apt-cache search adoptopenjdk` - shows a list of packages (versions) available (incl. v8 & v11)

If you want/need to build JDK, you can [start with this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NotAlexNoyle/c3b8c342105d700846825af838050199/raw/30422965cfb96c21e749287615779dc7ced07ee2/openjdk-12-pi-3-guide.txt).