# What Java version is best for running Java applications on Raspberry pi 3

Tags: java, raspbian

I am working on my own Java Application for Raspberry Pi3, it currently works on Java SE 10, and JavaFX 11, but it can run on Java SE 11 to but with an extra step. I tried to run the program but no luck, this is what I have tried.

1. Tried to install Java SE 10 with no luck because its not available
   to be installed on Rasbian
2. Download java see 10 and run manually but JavaFX won't work
3. Tried to install other OS but there were no Desktop options of Ubuntu
4. Downloaded Both Java 10 and 11 as tar files and made vm-argument to direct it manually to javafx folder, but I get error "Elf: not found", from what I read its a kernel issue meaning that kernel can't read or understand the program so it throughs that error.

After doing research I come to the conclusion that my setup won't work on Rasbian OS, so I am trying to figure out what will work the best for Rasbian OS, but I am not sure what Java version will work out of the box. I am aware Java 8 is available out of the box for Rasbian OS but I wanted to know other people's opinions on this situation and what is the most recommended Java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BellSoft LibericaJDK provides perfect Java JDK versions for Raspberry Pi which include JavaFX. For more information see https://webtechie.be/post/2020-04-08-installing-java-and-javafx-on-raspberry-pi/

For instance to install LibericaJDK 13

```
$ cd /home/pi
$ wget https://download.bell-sw.com/java/13/bellsoft-jdk13-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
$ sudo apt-get install ./bellsoft-jdk13-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me  I was beginning to think it wasn't possible - thank you!!